# Reporting tools comparison for Angular 7 project

Tags: angular, web, comparison, reporting

We are starting to build a new big web based project with Angular7 and need to choose right web based reporting tools to create system reports inside the application and maybe allow users to design their desired report templates runtime. I have done a lot of research on the internet to find the best choice, but didn't found very useful information.
Projects requirements are common requirements for reporting like:

- Different datasource type such as objectList or json
- paging
- Drill down
- Grouping
- Integration with Angular
- Good performance for big data
- Any other concern with web reporting that I'd better to consider or must take care of

Considering these common requirement can anyone make a brief comparison between top choices available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before going into details or features of a reporting tool, here is one reporting tool [stimulsoft](https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/productsstimulsoft). I do not work for them, just a little research.

Here's a little more precise definition of requirements.

I have developed extensively custom reporting tools for web apps, and would like to suggest a different view of the features required.

It is important to separate "Data Visualization" from "Reporting".

The features are different between both:
Visualization

- View Data In Grid or Chart format
- Group, filter, drill down
- Handle volumes
- Build Dashboard
- Eventually export some of the data
- Real time data visualization

Reporting

- Create and design multi-page reports
- Have fine control over the printed version
- Rich export features
- Have a report designer for on demand Reports development
- Have a report server in order to publish, share and secure access to reports

I will stop at this list. This will help you choose between both fields

For visualization, You can use Custom Grid Components, from many different vendors (kendo ui, IgniteUi, ag-grid and many more). Features to look for, are Grouping, hierarchy Grids, and Virtualization for performance.

For reporting, you have many different ones, which includes one I have mentioned above, which is compatible with JS.

As for reporting templates, up until now, I have created a custom solution, based on tokens, but mostly for data visualization or exporting.

As for the success of a reporting solution, it is important to build incrementally, and to make sure to know the ratio Visualization/Reporting (ex: 60%/40% of the features of each).

I hope this helps.

Kind Regards,